# Gradle build failed with an error without printing this error

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first Android project on Kotlin. I created a project and it builds successfully, don't know but after all, when I try to run the project on my device it says build failed without giving any error:

```
Gradle build failed with 1 error(s) in 352 ms
```

[image]

First I thought it may be an error of the JDK I use, but after changing the JDK version, again it gives the same error, I am stuck please help.

Comment: What's the version of Android Studio you are using? Did you check in the Gradle file is kotlin dependencies are included or not?

Comment: I m using a latest one i.e. android studio 3.6.1, and in project build.gradle -> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" , and in app's build.gradle it is-> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Comment: could you post the screenshot?

Comment: I can only see these two dependency of Kotlin in project

Comment: @AkshayNandwana yes, I posted did you see?

Comment: I don't think this should trouble in running the application. Did you try running the app?

Comment: yes I tried , it just synch and stop, without giving any red or blue error

Comment: go to the **Messages** tab it gives you the full details. Or go to a terminal and run `./gradlew build` to see the full details

Comment: I have two JDK in my pc, I used the "13.0.2"

Comment: hey thanx, there is an error which seems different i.e. -> Could not compile build file '/Users/ankitkumar/Desktop/onvifKotlin/OnvifTest/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score 2):

You need to build that [`onvifcamera`](https://github.com/rvi/ONVIFCameraAndroid/releases) from source, as the JAR seems to be built with Java 13.

```
 implementation "com.rvirin.onvif:onvifcamera:1.1.6"
```

Should be:

```
implementation project(":onvifcamera")
```

Older pre-packaged versions of the library might also work on Android.

Comment: hey really appreciate your answer it worked. but the above build failed error, I didn't get that. by the way, thank you for the reply.

Comment: One question per question; and this wasn't the actual question. Honestly, I have no clue why.